# OpenStack Autopilot

Tags: openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I am in the process of downloading the vSphere evaluation disc of ubuntu autopilot, I would be keen to hear from anyone who has deployed a Cloud with this software, like every single OpenStack deployment middleware I am assuming it is very restrictive? Does anyone know the answer to these questions:

What version of Keystone is deployed?
Can it deploy anything other that the IaaS packages?
What are the chances of deploying sahara, designate, trove, VPNaaS for Neutron, Murano, Manila, Magnum, Ceilometer?

Comment: What version of the Autopilot are you using? 16.03 deploys OpenStack Liberty, whilst the recent release of 16.06 deploys Mitaka.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the services you list in your question, Autopilot deploys Neutron. None of the other services are provisioned.

Autopilot builds a IaaS cloud using Nova, Swift, Neutron and Ceph backing Glance and Cinder (if that option was selected). The deployment is containerized using LXC, and orchestrated using Juju.

As you put it, the deployment UIs for Openstack offer limited options with the intent of simplifying the user experience for users who are not OpenStack wizards. If you have the necessary knowledge, you can build a more tailored OpenStack setup using Juju directly.

Comment: Kolla is pretty new, if you have a good experience, you should write a blog and share it! Safe streamlined choices for deploying OpenStack are Autopilot/Juju (Ubuntu),  Fuel (Ubuntu, RHEL), and Triple-O/Director (RHEL). Experts of course go for Apt or Yum plus vi ;-)

Comment: fuel is pretty cool, but still has no designate deployer, have you see the stack.sh script - holy sh1t!. https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack/blob/master/stack.sh